# How can I span all vaild input space using antlr4 instead of parsing a input?

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

In the other words, how can i get ast tree but with control of recursion depth.

e.g.

```
grammar: Expr

start: expression EOF;

expression
    : expression (+|-) expression
    | NUMBER
    ;

NUMBER: [0-9]+;
```

all valid input space with depth = 3:

depth 1:  0, 10, ...

depth 2: 0 + 2, 3 - 4, ...

depth 3: 0 + 2 - 4, ....

Comment: Are you trying to list the possible correct inputs? In other words, to use the grammar to generate sentences instead of parsing?

Comment: @rici yes. any ideas ? instead of using handwrite to implement all rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no feature built-in to Antlr parsers to do this, as far as I know, and a general solution would be complicated.

Even in your simple example, your question is hard to interpret. What is the recursion depth of a parse of a `NUMBER`? Always 1? One per iteration as though the repetition operator were expanded into BNF? Or was your intention to ignore the lexical analysis? (Remember that Antlr does not require that grammars be divided into lexical and syntactic components.)

Your grammar does not include any predicates but it's hard to write an Antlr grammar for real-world problems without using predicates; they are what give Antlr much of its power. But inverting a grammar which uses predicates is probably only possible by generating all candidates and then testing each one.

If we remove Antlr from the equation leaving only BNF, and don't attempt to generate tokens beyond their token type, then it's pretty simple to enumerate possible sentences using a breadth-first search, which will naturally work in order by recursion depth. The result is rarely useful because of exponential explosion in the number of possibilities, but there are certainly implementations.

A more common problem is that of generating useful test cases for a parser or language processor. The classic algorithm was presented in 1972 by Paul Purdom; although it is not entirely satisfactory, it forms the basis for many grammar testers. Open source implementations are available; if you want to write your own, try to find a copy of Malloy & Power's *An interpretation of Purdom's Algorithm for Automatic Generation of Test Cases*, first published in 2001.

Comment: Can generated test cases for a parser pass semantic analyze ?

Comment: @EadrenKing: If I understand your question correctly, then no. A context-free grammar is not powerful enough to represent the semantic constraints of a programming language. Rules like "variables must be declared before use" or "functions must have the same number of arguments as their declaration", are essentially context-dependent: the validity of an expression depends on declarations of the variables and functions used in the expression. So a context-free grammar is not going to help you to validate semantics, and therefore cannot be used to generate semantically-valid programs.

Comment: The best you can do with a context-free grammar is to generate programs which test the parser. But that's possibly not ideal either: if you test sentences generated by a context-free grammar with a parser generated from the same context-free grammar, what you are really testing is the parser generator. You are not verifying that the language of that grammar is the language you wanted to produce. So it's also important that you write your own test cases which demonstrate the particular constructs of the language you imagined, to see if your implementation complies.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. I have more cotext about the parser !